# Converting text to decimal in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

All, I would like to know how to (if its possible) to convert a text string like "AA" "AB" "AC" to a decimal value in Access. Here is my problem-

Management keeps track of several documents and all revisions. Documents are given a revision code of AA, AB or AC value where AA is an original, AB is the second iteration of the original document, AC is the third iteration of the document.

You see here AB has 18 released but, the real value is 36.

[image: screenshot]

Any Idea on how I could make this "Number of Revisions" column show the true value. My original table does NOT include ALL revisions, just current. thanks

Comment: You might not be able to post a picture, but you could post a *link* to a picture. Or, you could explain (in words) how you get "18" from "AB". I would have thought that "AB" meant [NumberOfRevisions]=1 (and [NumberOfRevisions]=0 would be the original "AA" document) ....

Comment: You are right, sorry. Here is a link to my querie output, http://imgur.com/XzwzxpC

AA= Original DOC 1
AB= revision of Original DOC 1
AC= Revision of AB revision 

Output is telling me that there have been 18 AB revisions released for review. But, that's where the number is wrong, it should be the 36.

Comment: Where does your [Number of Revisions] currently come from?

Comment: it comes from another query called [Q-AB]. Q-AB I have segregated all the AB's from my master Query called Q-ALL. Here is a screen shot of the design view- http://imgur.com/A6vnUHS

Comment: I still cannot follw. And the lack of interest in your question shows I am not the only one. Try to read this whole conversationa as someone who doesn't know your company/your problems and then fill in the answer to the questions you would have. Everybody here likes to help, but noone wants to keep asking you questions until it becomes clear what you want.